# Angular cdk overlay: viewport margin is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I noticed in my app that tooltips created with CDK Overlay doesn't respect viewport margin which I add with method `.withViewportMargin()`

I created simple reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewport-margin-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Overlay has been provided with two preferred positions:

- first opens upward
- second opens downward

I also added `.withViewportMargin(100)`. Red line shows where margin ends.

Overlay cannot be pushed and shrink:

```
.withPush(false)
.withFlexibleDimensions(false)
```

According to this configuration first position should be ignored and overlay should open on second position (downward).

Instead it ignores 100px viewport margin and still opens upward.
[image]

Can someone explain to me why this occurs?

**UPDATE:**

I've created an issue in angular material repository:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24259

Comment: were you able to fix this

Comment: @Amit No, I just overwrite preffered positions for elements near screen edge to open always downwards :(

Comment: Can you please show me what you have used

Comment: I just used `.withPositions()` method with only one position - see stackbliz example in my answer

Comment: this doesnot works for me. Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewport-margin-bug-uhcibj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yes, It works if you use `withPush(true)`, but in my case it is not solution - I use overlay for tooltips which should always open with corner aligned to (?) icon, upwards or downwards. `withPush(true)` moves tooltip and there is no more clear visual connection between tooltip and element it is describing